# BUG assertion triggered when replacing a physical page in a process

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I modified the Linux kernel in a way to have it modify some of the memory pages of a specific process. In summary, the functions I wrote receive a process id and address in that process, they then replace the page at that specific address with another dummy page. Finally, one of the functions call `__free_page()` on the original page that was replaced.

The problem is I get this error from the Linux kernel when it tries to reuse the original page. So, what is that flag it is complaining about? and how to get rid of this error? here is the relevant lines from syslog.

Thanks.

```
Nov 14 19:15:23 localhost kernel: [ 1466.949451] BUG: Bad page state in process mytestapp  pfn:7d309
Nov 14 19:15:23 localhost kernel: [ 1466.949452] page:ffffea0001f4c240 count:-1 mapcount:0 mapping:          (null) index:0x7fd632179
Nov 14 19:15:23 localhost kernel: [ 1466.949453] page flags: 0x100000000000000()
Nov 14 19:15:23 localhost kernel: [ 1466.949453] Modules linked in: test_module(O) acpiphp bnep rfcomm bluetooth binfmt_misc joydev hid_generic usbhid hid snd_ens1371 gameport snd_ac97_codec ac97_bus snd_pcm ghash_clmulni_intel snd_seq_midi snd_rawmidi snd_seq_midi_event ppdev snd_seq aesni_intel ablk_helper cryptd aes_x86_64 snd_timer snd_seq_device psmouse microcode snd vmw_balloon acpi_memhotplug parport_pc soundcore snd_page_alloc vmwgfx ttm mac_hid drm i2c_piix4 serio_raw shpchp lp parport e1000 mptspi mptscsih mptbase floppy vmw_pvscsi vmxnet3
Nov 14 19:15:23 localhost kernel: [ 1466.949484] Pid: 15064, comm: mytestapp Tainted: G    B      O 3.6.11-elasticos-0.01 #31
Nov 14 19:15:23 localhost kernel: [ 1466.949485] Call Trace:
Nov 14 19:15:23 localhost kernel: [ 1466.949487]  [<ffffffff8111941f>] bad_page+0xbf/0x110
Nov 14 19:15:23 localhost kernel: [ 1466.949505]  [<ffffffff8111aac9>] get_page_from_freelist+0x6f9/0x810
Nov 14 19:15:23 localhost kernel: [ 1466.949508]  [<ffffffff8111a702>] ? get_page_from_freelist+0x332/0x810
Nov 14 19:15:23 localhost kernel: [ 1466.949509]  [<ffffffff8111b06e>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x48e/0x9b0
Nov 14 19:15:23 localhost kernel: [ 1466.949512]  [<ffffffff8111f03a>] ? pagevec_lru_move_fn+0xea/0x110
Nov 14 19:15:23 localhost kernel: [ 1466.949514]  [<ffffffff81154ec3>] alloc_pages_vma+0xb3/0x190
Nov 14 19:15:23 localhost kernel: [ 1466.949515]  [<ffffffff811397cc>] handle_pte_fault+0x56c/0xb00
Nov 14 19:15:23 localhost kernel: [ 1466.949517]  [<ffffffff810473f7>] ? pte_alloc_one+0x37/0x50
Nov 14 19:15:23 localhost kernel: [ 1466.949527]  [<ffffffff8113afd9>] handle_mm_fault+0x259/0x340
Nov 14 19:15:23 localhost kernel: [ 1466.949538]  [<ffffffff8107c218>] ? up_read+0x18/0x30
Nov 14 19:15:23 localhost kernel: [ 1466.949540]  [<ffffffff816213d2>] do_page_fault+0x152/0x520
Nov 14 19:15:23 localhost kernel: [ 1466.949541]  [<ffffffff8108c36d>] ? set_next_entity+0x9d/0xb0
Nov 14 19:15:23 localhost kernel: [ 1466.949543]  [<ffffffff810135ca>] ? __switch_to+0x17a/0x410
Nov 14 19:15:23 localhost kernel: [ 1466.949545]  [<ffffffff8161de65>] page_fault+0x25/0x30
```

Comment: The problem is that some flags/fields in your page (struct page) in current state aren't consistent. You can check condition while this BUG occurs in kernel code http://lxr.free-electrons.com/

Comment: @AlexHoppus I know it does not like the flags of that page. I know also that the page's flags are checked against 'PAGE_FLAGS_CHECK_AT_PREP'. What I need to know is what the flags checked there mean? because every flag has a meaning (e.g. page present or page reserved?) and how to to get rid of that assertion.

Answer (score 0):

This macro checks that appropriate page flags are unset. As I see in your case you have problems with PG_LOCKED flag set. It means that you freed locked page. See unlock_page to handle this or (probably) use free_page instead